# Is it possible to automatically generate other drop-down menu items when you select a Google Form drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am creating a business application for renting products using spreadsheets and GAS, and I am thinking of accepting the rental process using Google Forms.
Therefore, I would like to select the product to rent from the Google Form drop-down menu, and then select the number of items to rent from the drop-down menu, but the number of products in stock should be updated in real time.
Therefore, when the item to be rented is selected from the drop-down menu, I would like to refer to the number of items in stock listed in the spreadsheet and set that number to the item in the drop-down menu.
However, I don't know how to dynamically create a drop-down menu (triggered by selecting the item to rent drop-down menu).

How can I dynamically set the dropdown menu items?

Comment: You cannot update Google Forms in "real time". For example, if one selects "Product X", then it is NOT possible to dynamically update a question referencing the number of available items for hire.  OTOH, there _may_  be a workarounds - some using Google Forms, and others using an external HTML (web site) form that integrates with Sheets. AAMOI, how many separate products are available for hr, and (in general terms) what is the range of units of each product available for hire)?